# How can I calculate the number of required samples for them to be statistically significant?

Tags: statistical-significance, sample-size

I have two sets of data samples. Each of these contain inference results that are either correct or incorrect (by "incorrect" we mean only false positives, there are no false negatives, similarly by "correct" we mean only true positives, there are no true negatives).

"Case" means site. For example on site number 5, camera performed an observation for certain amount of time (not known to me) and returned 7 images. 6 of them were classified correctly (true positives), 1 incorrectly (false negatives) by first algorithm. Then camera was working for some more time and returned 153 new images. These were only fed to second algorithm which returned 100 true positives and 53 false positives.

Here is data slice:

[image]

This has been returned to me by my customer who says that these are the cases where percentage of incorrect (misclassified) cases has risen after the usage of second algorithm and the counts of incorrect ones are significant enough to take a look at the results.

At first glance I can tell (unless I am wrong) that for example Case number 5 has not enough data samples run on the first algorithm to draw any conclusions. Case number 1 is similar but this time there is not enough data for samples run on the second algorithm.

1. Is there a way to tell what should be the minimal number of samples, to draw any conclusions?
2. How can I tell whether the second algorithm performs better - returns less incorrect results.
3. What tool can I use to answer the above? I have no experience in statistics, only in programming.

Comment: A few clarification questions: 1) What are the semantics of a "case" here (in the sense on whether the data you collected are dependent between the two algorithms)? You mentioned "Samples come from observations performed at different times for both algorithms" - does that mean at each of the 9 time points your customer run the inferences for _both_ algorithms, or they run the inferences for the two algorithms at 18 time points?

Comment: 2) What is the decision criteria? I personally find the "Incorrect %" you show in the image weird, it is the ratio between # incorrect and # correct instead of # incorrect and total number of (correct and incorrect) instances. This clearly has an impact on how one calculates the variances and hence determine significance.

Comment: 3) You mentioned in Q2 that you intend to find whether the second algorithm returns less false positives? Do you have the number of false positives in addition to the incorrectly classified samples (which include false positives and false negatives)?

Comment: @B.Liu many thanks for your interest. You are right about weirdness about ratio, my customer must have got that wrong. I've corrected the table. I've also clarified my question. There is no possibility to compare both algorithms on the same set of data.

Comment: "How can I tell whether the second algorithm performs better - returns less incorrect results." As far as the data show, if I understand them correctly, the second algorithm is clearly worse across the board - there are consistently higher percentages of incorrectness. Even without any considerations of significance, it is clear that these data cannot show that algorithm 2 is better, or that it will turn out to be better at any sample size. (Sample sizes seem to be large enough to say it's worse overall right now, even though this may not apply to every single case isolated.)

Comment: For a single case, you can run a chi squared test or a (basically equivalent) test to compare proportions to see whether the algorithm 2 result is significantly different from the algorithm 1 result. Required sample sizes depend on how much of a difference you want to be able to detect with a given probability - sample size calculations generally require such decisions by the user. Without any calculations I'd expect that for the shown data algorithm two is significantly worse for at least half of the cases if not more.

Comment: Note though that all such tests will assume independence of the individual images, of which I don't know whether it is appropriate here.

Comment: Further expanding on Christian's comments - what is a _meaningful_ difference in the proportion of incorrectly classified instances in your use case for you/your customer to be rightfully concerned? In my world I am may not even bother to run any statistical tests with this level of difference (10%+ absolute) by virtue of it qualifying under the [inter-ocular trauma test](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/11/inter-ocular-trauma-test/), but the level that this "test" kicks in may be different in your use case.